# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32console

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a module in Python 3.8 and it's giving me an error message. The module is win32console, and I have pywin32. 
The error is the following :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   win32console

Comment: There is no package [`win32console`](https://pypi.org/project/win32console/). Perhaps you mean [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but I had this problem too.
You need to install `pywin32` first.

Then `win32console` will be installed too because it's a part of `pywin32`

(you can use `pip install pywin32`)